# Integração SQL SERVER e Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que a autenticação do Active Directory aponte para uma base no SQL Server, a onde eu tenho usuário e senhas.
A questão é que tenho uma base de usuários e que todos os sistemas fazem autenticação nela, gostaria de utilizar essa mesma base para a autenticação dos usuários no domínio, pois manteria a mesma senha nas aplicações e no AD.

Comment: Você deseja autenticar seus usuários em um domínio, ou em uma aplicação?

Comment: A questão é basicamente a seguinte, eu tenho vários sistema e tenho o Active Directory, o que eu gostaria é que a base de usuários do Active Directory fosse a mesma das aplicações, pois caso o usuário trocasse a senha na aplicação ele conseguiria autenticar no domínio.

Comment: E se o usuário utilizar senhas diferentes em aplicações diferentes? Outra coisa, a ideia do AD é servir como um repositório central de informações de usuários e autoridade de autenticação. Talvez seja mais produtivo fazer com que as aplicações utilizem autenticação com segurança integrada, para que as credenciais sejam a do AD. Se isso não for o ideal para o seu caso, por favor edite a pergunta para indicar isso, assim você terá respostas melhores ;)

Comment: O usuário tem apenas uma senha, para todas as aplicações.
Não posso usar o AD como repositório central de informações.
Apenas gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que o AD utilize essa base já pronta de usuários.

Comment: edite a questão para incluir a informação de que você não pode usar a autenticação do AD. Caso contrário ninguém vai ver essa informação, pois poucas pessoas lêem os comentários. Se possível indique também por que você não pode usar o AD no seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, pois o AD utiliza uma base própria, então as informações ficam concentradas nessa base. Entretanto, é possível fazer o inverso. Basta criar uma aplicação adaptar suas aplicações para Single Sign On, ou seja, todas as telas de login da sua aplicação, serão direcionadas para uma aplicação específica e essa aplicação, fará a autenticação no AD.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on#Integrated_Windows_Authentication

http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, o Active Directory não consegue usar um banco de dados tercerizado. Dessa forma, não poderá configurá-lo para usar seu próprio.

Olhando rapidinho, o Active Directory tem algumas coisas que programas podem usar para interagir com AD. O *[Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170%28VS.85%29.aspx)* (em inglês) seria uma possível solução para contectar seus dados e colocá-los dentro do AD para usá-lo